# Rails callback to update another model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked the same question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389876/rails-callback-from-another-model) but probably it was not very clear.

I have a model User, with column `vote_weight` and `current_vote_weight`.

Each user can assign vote weight to another user temporarily. To achieve this I created a model `VoteWeightAssignment`, with columns `sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `temp_vote_weight`. temp_vote_weight is the amount of vote weight sent each time from a user to another.

VoteWeightAssignment model

```
belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: 'sender_id', class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :receiver, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', class_name: 'User'
```

Then on my users/show, I display vote weight sent and received for user logged in (current_user). To do so on my users controller show action I have:

```
@vote_weight_assignments_sent = VoteWeightAssignment.where(sender_id: current_user.id)
@vote_weight_assignments_received = VoteWeightAssignment.where(receiver_id: current_user.id)

@total_vote_weight_received = @vote_weight_assignments_received.to_a.sum(&:temp_vote_weight)
@total_vote_weight_sent = @vote_weight_assignments_sent.to_a.sum(&:temp_vote_weight)
@total_vote_weight = current_user.vote_weight + @total_vote_weight_received - @total_vote_weight_sent
```

This works fine.

Now what I want to achieve is that everytime a vote weight assignment is created or destroyed (I'm not allowing to edit it), on table users the column current_vote_weight should be updated for sender and receiver with the value of vote_weight + sum of vote weights received - the sum of vote weights sent.

Example:

user 1 has 10 vote weight

user 2 has 5 vote_weight

user 3 has 8 vote_weight

So my table users with columns id,vote_weight,current_vote_weight columns should be:

1,10,10

2,5,5

3,8,8

Then:

user 1 sends 3 vote weight to user 2

user 3 sends 4 vote weights to user 2

after this table vote_weight_assignments with columns sender_id,receiver_id,temp_vote_weight will be:

1,2,3

3,2,4

while users table should be:

1,10,7 (as he sent 3 vote weights)

2,5,12 (as he received 7 vote weights)

3,8,4 (as he sent 4 vote weight)

I understand I have to create a model method and a callback. The method should be on User model and called it by a callback on VoteWeightAssignment model. But I'm not sure how to implement it.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I added gem counter colture and added to users table 2 columns: received_vote_weight and sent_vote_weight which are updating with total vote weights sent and received for each user.

Then I created on user.rb

```
  after_commit :set_sender_current_vote_weight
  after_commit :set_receiver_current_vote_weight

  counter_culture :receiver, column_name: 'received_vote_weight', delta_column: 'temp_vote_weight'
  counter_culture :sender, column_name: 'sent_vote_weight', delta_column: 'temp_vote_weight'


  def receiver_current_vote_weight
    (receiver.vote_weight + receiver.received_vote_weight - receiver.sent_vote_weight)

  end

  def set_receiver_current_vote_weight
    receiver.update_attributes(current_vote_weight: receiver_current_vote_weight)
  end


  def sender_current_vote_weight
    (sender.vote_weight + sender.received_vote_weight - sender.sent_vote_weight)
  end

  def set_sender_current_vote_weight
    sender.update_attributes(current_vote_weight: sender_current_vote_weight)
  end
```

The last problem I have is that now it updates current_vote_weight column, but it does not include last record in the calculation.

Comment: How does user 1 have a current vote weight of 7 now when it was zero?

Comment: sorry my bad, i edited the question

Comment: user 1 current_vote_weight at the beginning is given by 10 + 0 (vote_weight received) - 0 (vote_weight sent) = 10

Comment: Although to be precise if there are no records yet on vote_weight_assignments the value on column current_vote_weight is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.

Added the gem counter-colture, generated a migration to create on users table columnsreceived_vote_weight and sent_vote_weight.

Added to vote_weight_assignment.rb

```
counter_culture :receiver, column_name: 'received_vote_weight', delta_column: 'temp_vote_weight'
counter_culture :sender, column_name: 'sent_vote_weight', delta_column: 'temp_vote_weight'
```

Added to user.rb

```
after_find :set_current_vote_weight

def current_vote_weight
  self.vote_weight - self.sent_vote_weight + self.received_vote_weight
end

def set_current_vote_weight
  self.update_attributes(current_vote_weight: current_vote_weight)
end
```

Now it works as expected, but the callback after_find updates users table too often. But I tried all callbacks on VoteWeightAssignment model and they were yes updating but they were not calculating last entry. Perhaps I'll post another question to fix this.